# Is it possible to write a SQL script for both MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sql-scripts, ansi-sql

I'd like to write a single SQL script that will run on a default installation of either MySQL or PostgreSQL (versions 5.5 and 9.0, respectively). Is this possible?
I can almost do it by adding `SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI';` to the start of the script and using standard ANSI queries, but that line isn't valid for PostgreSQL. I could tell PostgreSQL to continue on errors, but It'd be nice to have a script that runs without error.

Comment: as long as you don't use application specific non-standard SQL you should be fine.  I believe that's the point of SQL, it's structured (and standardized, more or less).  As to your point about `SET SESSION` you could run a PHP query checking for the installed db, before running the `SET SESSION`

Comment: how hard for your to save two different set of SQLs into two separate file?

Comment: ajreal: Harder than you'd think, due to all sorts of reasons not relevant to the question.

Comment: Patrick: Even simple standards aren't accepted by MySQL, e.g. double-quote marks are standard for quoting identifiers, and are accepted by PostgreSQL but not by MySQL. I will check out the PHP test, though.

Comment: you might have your constraints...take a look on wordpress installation script? **PS** write a cross database SQL vs load two set of SQLs for different databases, which is feasible for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using conditional comments:

```
/*! SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI'; */
```

PostgreSQL will ignore it, MySQL will run it. For more information see [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html).

**Update**: If you want to include commands that are run only on PostgreSQL but not on MySQL, you can exploit the fact that PostgreSQL supports nested comments, and MySQL doesn't. The following example shows how this could be used:

```
/*! SELECT 'MySQL' rdbms_type; */
/*/**/-- */ SELECT 'postgres' AS rdbms_type;
```

But this would probably make the file very difficult to read.

Comment: That's what I want, though I get a MYSQL error unless I put the `;` outside the MySQL comment, like this: `/*! SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI' */;`

Comment: Are you getting the error in MySQL or PostgreSQL? Are you sure that error isn't actually a problem with whatever SQL client you are using?

Comment: I'm just using `mysql`. If I put in `/*! SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI'; */` it completes the SET SESSION command properly, but continues to wait for input. If I stop that with `;` I get this: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*/' at line 1`. Moving `;` outside the comment fixes it, though I guess not for the reason I thought.

Comment: Okay, I guess the problem is the `mysql` client command line tool. The command line tool splits your input at every semicolon it sees, and then sends each command separately. So the server receives two commands: `/*! SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI'` and `*/`. The first command works fine, and the second command causes the syntax error. You could type `delimiter $$` in the mysql client, and then the commands would not be split on semicolons (but on `$$`) before sending to the server.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to write a SQL script for both MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Yes.

Next question, please!

...

Okay, in all seriousness, it's totally doable, *but* you have to be aware of the things that each does differently.  For example, if you need to use a `bytea` in PG, but a `BLOB` in MySQL, you're going to have a really fun time getting the encoding/escaping correct.  Then there's things like fulltext searching.  PG has it built in, MySQL has it built in to only one table type (MyISAM, the sucky one), and the syntax is totally different.  And this doesn't even touch character sets and collations.

If you limit yourself to simple CRUD operations, you're probably good to go.  Heck, if you've done your job right, you can also probably use the same exact code to talk to SQLite and MSSQL (when switched to ANSI mode).

Once you even get moderately complex, your code is going to need to at least be *aware* of the underlying database to work around the small behavior and syntax differences.  The important part is that the majority of your queries can be shared between underlying databases without any modification whatsoever *if* you construct them properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in for a one-by-one feature comparison. I didn't read the whole link but I think it might be usefull in your quest.

http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/

Answer (score 1):

Set the mode in the server not in the script:

> You can set the default SQL mode by starting mysqld with the --sql-mode="modes" option, or by using sql-mode="modes" in my.cnf (Unix operating systems) or my.ini (Windows).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html

Obviously in the script your going to have use the lowest common dominator of features that both accept. MySQL is also known to have the most standard compliant parser but that does not mean it actually mean it will do anything (Good way to get Gotcha'd since the scripts will both work but behaviour may be totally different). Postgresql is not 'ansi' compliant either. It may come the closest but it has plenty of things unique to itself. Does not seem like an ideal way.

ORM's work hard at doing this same kind of thing - taking the pain out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI';
```

Without the conditions (?) solves the ulogin php library install problem.
Also helpful to add `use database;` if you already created it on the command line.